# Is separability + connectedness in metric spaces sufficient to guarantee path connectedness? Are these necessary conditions?

Tags: general-topology

Saw someone make this claim, but I'm not certain this is true. Can't think of counterexamples in either direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is false, but I'm willing to be wrong.

Comment: @Randall Yeah, this is why it would be nice to see counterexamples in either(or both) direction.

Comment: Let $S$ be thre closure in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of $S_1=\{(t,\sin{1/t}),0 < t \leq 1\}$, so that $S=S_1\cup S_2$ where $S_2=\{0\} \times [-1,1]$. Then $S$ is second-countable, metric, connected but not path-connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) is a classical counterexample.

Comment: To clarify, this is a counterexample to the title question; the body also asks the converse (which has the same answer).

Answer (score 2):

Complementing mathcounterexamples.net's answer, it's not a *necessary* condition either. Consider an "uncountable starfish" - take uncountably many copies of the unit interval, and glue them together at their $0$-endpoints. This is path-connected but not separable.

---

A bit more rigorously: take an uncountable set $A$, and consider the set $X=(A\times(0,1])\sqcup\{*\}$. We put a metric $d$ on $X$ as follows:

- For each $x\in X$ we set $d(x,x)=0$.
- For each $a\in A, i\in (0,1]$ we set $d(*,\langle a,i\rangle)=d(\langle a,i\rangle, *)=i.$
- For each $a\in A$ and each **distinct** $i,j\in (0,1]$ we set $d(\langle a,i\rangle , \langle a,j\rangle)=\vert i=j\vert$.
- Finally, for each **distinct** $a,b\in A$ and each $i,j\in (0,1]$ we set $d(\langle a,i\rangle ,\langle b,j\rangle)=i+j.$

It's a good exercise to check that this $d$ is in fact a metric on $X$, and that the resulting topology is path-connected. But it's clearly not separable: given a countable set of points $C\subseteq X$, since $A$ is uncountable we can find some $a\in A$ which is *not* the left coordinate of any point in $C$, and then $\langle a,1\rangle$ is at distance at least one from any point in $C$.

Comment: $\ell^\infty$ I’d a counterexample that’s also a linear space. Of course connectedness *is* necessary for path-connectedness.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sure, but - while of course far more important and natural - that's harder to whip up. I think there's some value to the OP in thinking about "blunt" constructions like this.